# How do I run my main function when using the Rust IntelliJ plugin?

Tags: intellij-idea, rust

I'm coming from Eclipse + Java, so I'm used to writing a `main` function inside some class file if I'd like to quick-and-dirty test something.
In Eclipse I can simply click the "run" button or hit <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd> to launch my `main` function.

I'd like to do the same thing in Rust + IntelliJ. I've created a new file "Main2.rs" and pasted a hello world sample into it:

[image: IntelliJ + Rust sample; run button is disabled]

I hit the compile button and voila - **the run button stays disabled?!?**

`rustc "Main2.rs" && ./Main2` works of course, but how can I get IntelliJ to execute that simple "Hello World" by pressing the "run" button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see two reasons why you might be unable to run your program:

**The name of the file you are trying to run:**

Cargo looks for a `lib.rs` or `main.rs` (for binary projects) in your `src/` directory when building your project.

If you want to build using Cargo, you should rename your `Main2.rs` to `main.rs` and make sure that it is in your `src/` directory (and that there is no `lib.rs` there).

**You have no run configurations:**

If your file is named `main.rs`/`lib.rs`, you should see a green arrow next to your `fn main()`. Clicking this will automatically add a new run configuration and run your program.

You can also manually add a run configuration by clicking on the dropdown menu next to 'Build' on your toolbar and selecting 'Edit Configurations...'.

More information on creating and editing run configurations is available [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html).

Comment: OK, after moving the file from "src" to "examples" I got such an arrow.
Thank you for pushing me in the right direction :)

Comment: @Hoeze If my answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted. Otherwise, please let me know what problem you are having so I can revise my answer.